# How to organize the download of data with the authorization check in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

When you step on the rout triggered a particular controller and loads the data.

```
angular.module('app.Images', [])

    .controller('ImagesCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window, imagesUrl) {
        var _this = this;

        this.images = {};

        $http.get(imagesUrl)
          .then(checkResponse);

        function checkResponse (data) {
          if (data.success && data.data) {
            _this.images = data.data;
          } else if (data.error) {
            alert(data.error);
          } else if (data.reload) {
            $window.location.reload(true);
          }
        }
```

On each route have to check `data.reload`.

How best to do data load and such checks at all entry points?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to ask here.  you may want to consider changing to `.then()` instead of the deprecated `.success()`, then re-word your question if you are still having issues.

Comment: Claies, ок. Thanks i did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You need to globally check the `data.reload` (if i understand You correctly) then You can user interceptors (`$httpProvider.interceptors`). You can read about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in the interceptors part.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function ($q) {
  return {
    'response': function(result) {
      //check data.reload here
      return $q.resolve(result);
    }
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an response interceptor to $http, either globally or specific to certain requests.

Sample global response interceptor:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($window) {
  return {
    response: function(response) {
       if(response.data && response.data.reload) {
            $window.location.reload(true);
       }
    }
  };
});
```

More about interceptors at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http